# Run multiple python file concurrently

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

how to run multiple files of python simultaneously

I have three files pop.py pop1.py pop2.py i want to run this file concurrently
this files are getting run one by one
python code to run all files

Comment: You need to start different processes (threads aren't enough) so the easiest way is to start them manually.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverfow. You are much more likely to get relevant answers if you can include some code in the question along with a description of what you expect to happen and what actually happens. This site is mostly about helping people to get their existing code working. even if it's a shell script - just let us see what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make main() function in every python file and then import all the files in your main file. Then call all main functions.

```
from . import pop
from . import pop1
# and so on

# and now call all main functions
pop.main()
pop1.main()
# and so on
```

Answer (score 7):

You can easily accomplish this with the subprocess module.

```
import subprocess

process1 = subprocess.Popen(["python", "pop.py"]) # Create and launch process pop.py using python interpreter
process2 = subprocess.Popen(["python", "pop1.py"])
process3 = subprocess.Popen(["python", "pop2.py"])

process1.wait() # Wait for process1 to finish (basically wait for script to finish)
process2.wait()
process3.wait()
```

Comment: I want to run each file simultaneously

Comment: this runs all of them simultaneously, the only delay between the start times of the processes is the execution of the Popen function which is insignificant

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be a python solution? With the problem as stated, it might be easiest to just start all three in bash:

```
python pop.py &
python pop1.py &
python pop2.py &
wait # wait for all three to finish, if needed
```

While this solution runs them concurrently, you should think about *why* you want them to be concurrent. Are you trying to parallelize your computation? Are the processes communicating (e.g. a Producer/Consumer pattern)? Are there any dependencies between them? In all but the simplest cases, you would usually be better served by bundling all three python modules together into a python package and adding some runner code which imports all three, starts each as a thread (see oren revenge's answer), and handles any inter-process communication.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to read about [threading](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html) within Python. You should think about rearranging your code in one file.

**PSEUDOCODE**

```
import threading

class Pop(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        # Content from "pop.py"
        # Maybe some some changes are needed


class Pop1(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        # Content from "pop1.py"


# ...

pop = Pop()
pop1 = Pop1()
# ...

pop.start()
pop1.start()
# ...
```

---

Answer (score 1):

```
import test1,test2
from threading import Thread

Thread(target=test2.main).start()
Thread(target=test1.main).start()
```

This script runs test1.py and test2.py concurrently.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

create a **Shell file** like this

```
 python pop.py
 python pop1.py
 python pop2.py
```

and run **.sh** file.
**.sh** Run multiple file one by one

Comment: As written, this would run the three files sequentially.